# MATLAB Optical character recognition - need help

Tags: matlab, ocr

I have to use mat lab to find a certain letter in a tif text image.In the spatial domain. I have no idea how to do this, and can't find any documentation other than complex code that uses loops, loops are forbidden. Yes, this is an assignment I don't want the answer just some direction on how to even start.

I want to use imfilter and use a letter as a template or filter to imfilter using correlation but from there I have no idea where to go and don't even know what questions to ask to find more info on mat labs site.

The write up makes it seem simple but I know nothing of this subject as I am a beginner so to me this is hard.

thanks

Comment: "Loops are forbidden"?  What sort of nonsensical assignment is this?

Comment: That's what I say, he does not specify where and when we can use loops, I want to break the text up line by line and filter for a match. All it says is your graded on the number of loops you use. I tried to ask for clarification but so far I have not gotten any. So I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox I would suggest using the function [normxcorr2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/normxcorr2.html). It calculates the normalized cross correlation between a template image and a larger image, which I think is what you want.

You don't need any for loops to use it, but the method itself probably uses for loops somewhere hidden in the code. I don't know if that counts..

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I can use that function, the class says to use filter function because it returns the result of the mask over the whole image and from there use the find function. I get the theory but so far I know jack about how to get rid of noise and not have false matches.

Comment: The normxcorr2 function also returns the result of the mask (the template) over the whole image, and you then use max and find to find the location of the peaks in correlation. 

But if your assignment demands the use of the imfilter function, you should of course use it.